# Direct uploading returning incorrect src with Image Element

Tags: jquery, cloudinary

I'm using the JQuery plugin and unsigned image uploader with Cloudinary. My images are uploaded successfully, but the HTML image element returned from bind '*cloudinarydone*' contains **file://** prefix so the [examples](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud) given do not load the $.cloudinary.image(); object properly. Am I missing something?

HTML:

```
   `<form type="multipart/form-data" class="upload_form"></form>
    <div class="preview"></div>`
```

Javascript:

```
    $('.cloudinary_fileupload').bind('fileuploadstart', function (e) {
          $('.preview').html('Upload started...');
    }).bind('cloudinarydone', function (e, data) {
        $('.preview').append(
           $.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id,
            {
                format: 'jpg', width: 150, height: 100,
                crop: 'thumb', gravity: 'face', effect: 'saturation:50'
            })
    );
    return true;
});
```

[Image: chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qg87.png)

Comment: It seems you are loading your page with the `file://` protocol (without a webserver). Reload it from your `http://localhost/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kaido, you're correct it worked straight away with http:

> It seems you are loading your page with the file:// protocol (without a webserver). Reload it from your http://localhost/